# How can I get the list of computer names in Windows Network using Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, lan

I know that the Ruby have a lot of gems allowing programmers write a really beatiful code.
This short example by default scans all addresses on subnet 192.168.1.x.

```
require 'ipscanner'
a = IPScanner.scan
#=> ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.4"]
```

How can I get computer names instead of ip's? Is there any gem that implements Window API (NetBIOS)?
Maybe it's better to use smth. like macaddr http://rubygems.org/gems/macaddr that parse 'ipconfig /all' (in my case - 'nbtstat')

Comment: Do not overformat your question. No need for lots of bold or caps.

Answer (score 2):

That [ipscanner gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ipscanner/0.1.8/frames) looks like it just cycles through 192.168.1.(1..254) and builds an array of the ip addresses that didn't timeout this line: [TCPSocket](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html).new(ip_address)

So one method might be to reverse lookup the host name given an IP address. Looks like the [Socket class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) can help you out.

For instance:

```
Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = false
s = Socket.getaddrinfo(’66.249.67.49′,nil)
hostname = s[0][4]
```

or

```
host = Resolv.new.getname('66.249.67.49')
```

Code taken from a [blog](http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/resolve-a-hostname-from-an-ip-address-in-ruby-reverse-dns/).

I don't have any computers on the network to test this, and I don't know enough about this stuff to know if there's a difference between a computer's name at an IP and the host name at an IP. If the above doesn't work, it can't be too far off.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @danneu.

I wrote simple example, works great on Windows 7.
Check your firewall policy (you can get just ip instead of computer name)! Name of the computer is the third parameter so use hostname = Socket.getaddrinfo('192.168.1.10', nil)[0][2].

```
require 'ipscanner'
Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = false
IPScanner.scan.each { 
    |i|
    puts "#{Socket.getaddrinfo(i, nil)}"    
}
```

Output:

```
[["AF_INET", 0, "STARBOY", 192.168.1.2, 2, 0, 0]]
[["AF_INET", 0, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1, 2, 0, 0]]
[["AF_INET", 0, "mcx-PC", 192.168.1.4, 2, 0, 0]]
```

This example is more illustrative and it works consistently waiting for the completion of all threads. Pingecho timeout increased to 50 ms.

```
require 'ipscanner'

puts 'List of computers in your LAN. Please wait ...'

class IPScanner
    # override scan method
    def self.scan(ip_base = '192.168.1.', range = 1..254, t = 50)
        computers = [] 
        threads = []  
        Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = false    
        (range).map { 
            |i| 
            threads << Thread.new {
                ip = ip_base + i.to_s
                if pingecho(ip, t) 
                    computers << Socket.getaddrinfo(ip, nil)[0][2]                    
                end
            }
        }.join      
        # wait for all threads to terminate
        threads.each { |thread| thread.join }
        return computers
    end
end

puts "#{IPScanner.scan}"
```

Output:

```
["STARBOY", "192.168.1.1", "mcx-PC"]
```